# obj expected error when run javascript function in asp form (visual studio)

Tags: javascript

i get obj expected error when click on asp button. where is the problem?

code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script type"text/javascript">
    Hmove=-100;
    function moveObjRight(obj) {
    obj.style.left=Hmove;
    Hmove+=2;
    if(Hmove<100)           
    window.setTimeout("moveObjRight(" +obj.id+ ");", 0);
    }
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<style type="text/css">
    #AS
    {
        top: 141px;
        left: 118px;
        position: absolute;
        height: 25px;
        width: 25px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<img alt="asd" src="pic 3-4.jpg" id="AS"/>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="moveObjRight(AS);"/>
</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're missing the closing brace of your `moveObjRight()` function. Could that be the problem?

Comment: ya that was it but now i get this one: 'AS' is undefined

Comment: This got nothing to do with Visual Studio or ASP, it's pure JavaScript issue. Irrelevant tags removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is inconsistent about how it references the object it is moving.
On this line you are missing the quotes - there is no AS object, it's the string id of the oject

```
OnClientClick="moveObjRight(AS);"
```

should be

```
OnClientClick="moveObjRight('AS');"
```

Your function is expecting an object not a string

```
function moveObjRight(obj)...
```

should be

```
function moveObjRight(objId) {
```

var obj = document.getElementById(objId);
   ...
now this line will work

```
window.setTimeout("moveObjRight(" +obj.id+ ");", 0);
```

but you could just use

```
window.setTimeout("moveObjRight(" +objId+ ");", 0);
```

Comment: i did what you said but now obj.style.left=Hmove;
 isnt work (error : obj undefined)

Comment: i add     var obj = document.getElementById(objId);     in function but still got this error : 'AS' is undefined